# How to convert Ext.data.TreeStore loading from file to loading from .net webservice?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extjs, extjs4

I have a Ext.data.TreeStore which read data from text file :

[image]

```
this.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        model: "GeoExt.data.LayerTreeModel",
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: 'data/test.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'children',
                idProperty: 'Id'
            }
        }),
        folderSort: true
    });
```

This is the file content:

```
[
    {
        text: "Category1",
        leaf: false,
        expanded: true,
        checked: false,
        children: [
            {
                text: "A1",
                layer: "A2",
                name: "A3",
                leaf: true,
                checked: false,
                nodeType: "gx_layer"
            },
            {
                text: "B1",
                layer: "B2",
                name: "B3",
                leaf: true,
                checked: false,
                nodeType: "gx_layer"
            }
            ],
        nodeType: "gx_layer"
    },
    {
        text: "Category2",
        leaf: false,
        expanded: true,
        checked: false,
        children: [
            {
                text: "C1",
                layer: "C2",
                name: "C3",
                leaf: true,
                checked: false,
                nodeType: "gx_layer"
            }],
        nodeType: "gx_layer"
    }
]
```

I've noticed in firebug that the get doesn't return JSON struct , but plain text. but it works.

[image]

I want to get the same result but getting the tree nodes from webservice (which brings it back from postgres).

The first simplest thing I tried was (also tried text/json):

```
[WebMethod]        
        public void GetJSON()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";

            string res = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\test.json");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(res);
        }
```

And I'm getting error :

```
Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/getJSON'.
```

which make sense because the file isn't JSON (but this is how I managed to make it work).

I would like help with 2 things :

1. What is the correct JSON format I need to use to get the same result as I got in this example ?
2. How do I serve the same data from webservice ?

Thank you !

***************** SOLUTION ******************

Based on Meister answer , the method needs to look like :

```
[WebMethod] 
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]       
public void GetJSON()
{
Object res = new Object();
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string str = js.Serialize(res);
Context.Response.Clear();
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
Context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=export.json");
Context.Response.Flush();
Context.Response.Write(str);
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with .NET, but the content type for JSON is `application/json`. Also, proper JSON needs quotes around the object property names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try replace:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
```

with this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
```

**UPDATE:**
You can also try add **`[ScriptService]`** on top of the web service class.

Anyway, I think it doesn't make sense to read a JSON file from a web service. You could just read it from the JSON reader like you did in your first code sample. I use web service to handle the passed parameter and cook up something (like a JSON object) to response back.

Comment: Your answer is half correct but I wanted to give you the credit.
I've updated my question with entire solution.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problems completely? If not then tell me what's still bugging you. And can you show me your response text form the web service? Is it the same as your wanted format?

Comment: I've edited the bottom of my question with complete solution. you can copy it

Comment: It looks a lot different than my solution, but maybe because I was using Handler instead of WebService. Thanks anyway :)